# OpenCV: how to change color of all non transparent pixels to black?

Tags: java, opencv, android

I use OpenCV (Java) and I want to change color of all the non transparent pixels in my Mat to black (colors defined in ARGB_8888 but could be another format)

How can I do that ?

```
  Mat mat = new Mat();
  bmp32 = bitmap.copy(Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888, true);
  Utils.bitmapToMat(bmp32, mat);
// and then ????
```

Thanks !

Answer (score 1):

```java
// allocate space as mixChannels requires so
Mat bgr = new Mat(mat.size(), CvType.CV_8UC3);
Mat alpha = new Mat(mat.size(), CvType.CV_8U);
List<Mat> src = new ArrayList<Mat>();
src.add(mat);
List<Mat> dst = new ArrayList<Mat>();
dst.add(alpha);
dst.add(bgr);
// A->alpha, RGB->bgr in reverse order
MatOfInt fromTo = new MatOfInt(0,0, 1,3, 2,2, 3,1);
mixChannels(src, dst, fromTo);

// now, make non-transparent parts black
Mat mask;
compare​(alpha, Scalar(0), mask, opencv_core.CMP_EQ);
Mat res;
Core.bitwise_and(bgr, bgr, res, mask);
```

Comment: I have not tested the code and I am not familiar with Java, so please feel free to edit any mistake.

Comment: Thanks! I have updated your code with MatOfInt for fromTo. Still have an error on "Mat mask = alpha == 0;" : "Operator '==' cannot be applied to 'org.opencv.core.Mat', 'int'" Any idea how to correct this line ? Thanks a lot !

Comment: @Regis_AG Maybe `Mat mask = alpha == Scalar(0);` works. I have editted the code.

Comment: Tried "Mat mask = alpha == new Scalar(0);" Error: "Operator '==' cannot be applied to 'org.opencv.core.Mat', 'org.opencv.core.Scalar'" Any other idea? I have no idea...

Comment: @Regis_AG Did you try `compare` function, as in the last edit?